# Como armazenar em um campo AGM uma valor de uma tabela no banco de dados?

Tags: html, angular, firebase, google-maps

Olá estou desenvolvendo um projeto com Angular, Firebase e Android. O projeto é um sistema de rastreio,pelo o aplicativo do celular é pego a localização, em Longitude e latitude, e esses valores são jogados no Firebase.
Com uma dashboard criada no Angular, a mesma deve ler e projetar a localização utilizando o AGM (Angular Google Maps) o mesmo já foi configurado e está funcional.

```
import {AgmCoreModule} from '@agm/core';
imports: AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'minha chave'
    })
```

Esse é o formato para projetar o google maps:

```
<agm-map class="mapa1" [latitude]="lat" [longitude] = "lng">
        <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude] ="lng"> </agm-marker> 
      </agm-map>
```

tanto a variável "lat" e "lng" estão armazenadas no component.ts

```
export class PerfilmotoristaComponent implements OnInit {
 lat =-23.774109;
  lng =  -49.948239;
}
```

eu gostaria que fosse possível substituir esses valores estáticos por valores que são gerados no firebase.
ps: O Firebase já está configurado no projeto

Comment: ja tentou this.firebase.pegarDados().subscribe(dados=>{ this.lat=dados.lat...

Comment: o this.lat = dados seria o nome do campo da minha tabela?

Comment: Para você transferir os dados do Firebase para o seu projeto, você tem que fazer o bind entre o componente html que você quer que receba os dados, para isso você deve criar uma variável em seu component.ts igual ao do campo value do seu component, no caso lat e ing, essas variáveis vão receber os dados do seu getService como o Eduardo passou ali.

Comment: Na parte de fazer o o get deu tudo certo igual o Eduardo cometou, mas ao passar isso pro agm ele joga a localização pro mar, o que poderia ser?